# Not cooking USB3 ports on Linux?

Tags: linux, usb, bandwidth, hang, stability

I'm still using an 11" Linux notebook bought in 2016 as a beater and "kitchen workstation". It has a single USB3 which works fine in itself but has a tendency to get cooked. I say cooked because it will happen almost inevitably when I/O over it gets too intensive.

As an example: yesterday I copied about 260Gb twice using zfs send/receive (comparable to rsync), from an internal HDD to an external SDD and later to an external HDD. Peak speed was about 70MB/s. When I copied a much smaller amount from an internal to an external SSD the operation hung, forcing me to power-cycle the machine because there was no way to kill the process(es) involved (the copy had reached about 141MB/s at an earlier point). The same thing had happened a few days earlier trying to format that same external SSD to NTFS.

I never tried this machine under MSWin so have no idea if this is a hardware issue or rather something at the OS level. The only diagnostic info I get is kernel oopsie dumps in the syslog, about a process being hung.

Kernel in use is 4.14; I tried newer ones but 4.14 seems to be a sweet spot.

Any idea what this can be and how to avoid it?

Comment: I am not sure what you mean by 'cooked'. Is it complete broken, made slower 'forever' or made slower temporarily (while hot, but fast again after cooling down)? Or something else? Are you sure it it related to temperature? Are you sure that the USB3 port is the bottleneck? Or maybe the USB 3 device? Have you considered buffering of data in RAM? Maybe 70MB/s shows the real transfer speed to the memory cells and 141MB/s shows the speed to RAM.

Comment: Sometimes it's the hard disk's firmware that doesn't work properly with UAS. As UAS is (officially) supported only with USB3, the problem wouldn't happen with USB2. Search on this site for the word "UAS".

Comment: I actually borrowed the word "cooked" from someone else who used it to describe what seemed to be similar problems. What I mean is that the transfer stops, and the process(es) involved hang with possibility to kill them (which is also why a normal reboot doesn't complete). Temperature could in fact be involved; I have USB3 thumb drives that get very hot and the plugs of external drives too. There seems to be some circuitry in the connector on the motherboard; I guess that a thermal protection at that level could cause software to hang if the connection were frozen that way.

Comment: I haven't yet seen this kind of behaviour on other systems running OS X or MSWin, which suggests UAS incompatibility isn't the issue. Would I find incompatibility data by searching for UAS on here?

Comment: You'd find how to disable UAS for a device. Usually it's a specific device - OS combo that fails. Providers of such products ensure it always work with Windows and MacOS, not so much with Linux.

Comment: @RJVB, You mentioned 'zfs send/receive (comparable to rsync)'. Maybe you can avoid hanging the process(es), if you limit the transfer speed. It is possible with `rsync --bwlimit=RATE ...`. See details in `man rsync`. (I don't know the tool you are using, maybe there is a similar option there, maybe you can try with `rsync`.)

Comment: Yes, thanks, I had that same idea, just haven't had the occasion to test it yet. If that works I can do something similar by using `zfs send | pv -L xyz | zfs receive`.

Comment: Re: my "I haven't yet seen this kind of behaviour on other systems running OS X or MSWin, which suggests UAS incompatibility isn't the issue" : I think I now did. The same ASM1153-based enclosure that's experienced/triggered hangs on LInux also had/caused on an old slow Win10 machine with only USB2. Win10 seems to support UAS over USB2, is that possible?

Comment: UAS is a suggestion only. You have to confirm (on Linux, no idea for Windows) that it's in use. Usually: plug the disk, run as root `dmesg | grep -i uas` . If this doesn't appear then that idea was wrong.